# Angular web application Databinding is not working

Tags: c#, angularjs, wcf

I am consuming wcf rest service into angular js application. I am trying to display single record in angular js application based on Account Holder Last Name and parameters type is string . The method types is GET .when the post the value to wcf service and its receive the values .Its check the values in ado.net code whether the values is valid or invalid .  Its able to retrieve Account Holder information in Google chrome network tap response section. But the problem is not displaying anything in webpage .

Here is the Interface .

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    UriTemplate = "/GetCustomers/{Account_Holder_Last_Name}")]
    string GetCustomers(string Account_Holder_Last_Name);
```

Here is the Implementation .

```
 public string GetCustomers(string Account_Holder_Last_Name)
        {

            List<object> customers = new List<object>();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Current_Account_Holder_Details WHERE Account_Holder_Last_Name =@Account_Holder_Last_Name";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Holder_Last_Name", Account_Holder_Last_Name);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (sdr.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (sdr.Read())
                            {

                                customers.Add(new
                                {
                                    Tittle = sdr["Tittle"],
                                    Account_Holder_First_Name = sdr["Account_Holder_First_Name"],
                                    Account_Holder_Last_Name = sdr["Account_Holder_Last_Name"],
                                    Account_Holder_DOB = sdr["Account_Holder_DOB"],
                                    Account_Holder_House_No = sdr["Account_Holder_House_No"],
                                    Account_Holder_Street_Name = sdr["Account_Holder_Street_Name"],
                                    Account_Holder_Post_Code = sdr["Account_Holder_Post_Code"],

                                    Account_Holder_Occupation = sdr["Account_Holder_Occupation"],
                                    Account_Number = sdr["Account_Number"]



                                });
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }

                return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(customers));
            }

        }
```

Here is the Script code .

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
      app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
          $scope.IsVisible = false;
          $scope.Customers = [];
          $scope.Search = function () {
              var post = $http({
                  method: "GET",
                  url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetCustomers/" + encodeURIComponent($scope.Account_Holder_Last_Name),
                  dataType: 'json',
                  headers: {
                      'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                  }
              });

              post.success(function (data, status) {
                  $scope.Customers = eval(data.d);
                  $scope.IsVisible = true;
              },
                  function (err) {
                      console.log("Some Error Occured." + err);
                  }
              );

              post.error(function (data, status) {
                  $window.alert(data.Message);
              });
          }
      });
    </script>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="Account_Holder_Last_Name" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="Search()" />
        <hr />
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ng-show="IsVisible">
            <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                <th> Tittle</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th> Last Name</th>
                <th>  DOB </th>
                <th> House No</th>
                <th> Street Name</th>
                <th>Post Code</th>
                <th> Occupation</th>
                <th>Account Number</th>


            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{m.Tittle}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_First_Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_Last_Name}}</td>

                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_DOB}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_House_No}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_Street_Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_Post_Code}}</td>

                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_Occupation}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Number}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the screen shot wcf service receiving the values .
[image]

Here is the screen shot Google chrome network tab able to catch the data and web page does not displaying the data . 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far, as I can see from your Chrome dev tools screenshot, you are actually receiving string that contains JSON and not a JSON as is, which is rather strange practice. Also the root object of JSON in response string is actually Array. Since string does not contain property `d`, I assume you should change the code from:

```
$scope.Customers = eval(data.d);
```

to

```
$scope.Customers = JSON.parse(data);
```

Also, I'm not aware about `.success(`, but for the promise returned by `$http()`, success callback receives the whole response object (that includes status, data, headers, etc.) and not only response data as first argument.

***Tip:***

By the way, doing `eval(...)` is a very bad practice not only in AngularJS, but in JavaScript in general. You should consider to return pure JSON from server and not wrap it with string as you have now.

---

***Edit (example of final code):***

Your Search function may look something like this:

```
$scope.Search = function () {
          var post = $http({
              method: "GET",
              url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetCustomers/" + encodeURIComponent($scope.Account_Holder_Last_Name),
              dataType: 'json',
              headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
              }
          });

          post.then(function (response) { // .success(function(data => .then(function(response
              var data = response.data; // extract data from resposne
              $scope.Customers = JSON.parse(data); // eval(data.d) => JSON.parse(data)
              $scope.IsVisible = true;
          }, function (err) {
              $window.alert(err);
          });
}
```

***Live Demo***

https://plnkr.co/edit/0pkO8NWP2A7XerLc2NhO?p=preview

Comment: @Mohammad see my edit with example of Search function

Comment: Thanks you very much . its really solve my big problem . Thanks once again @Vadim